# Getting IDs for nested arrays extracted from JSON docs

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv

I have a Python code that takes JSON documents from a local MongoDB, extracts nested arrays and replaces them with ids. It then exports the three resulting sets of data to CSV files. It works well, but it's missing one thing: I need to add a post_id column to the resulting tags and comments files so that I can correspond comments and tags to the post where they're taken from.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
import json
import csv
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId, json_util


# Function to extract arrays and replace them with ID
def process_json(json_data):
    result = {}
    arrays = {}

    item_id = json_data["_id"]

    if isinstance(item_id, dict):
        item_id = item_id["$oid"]

    if isinstance(item_id, ObjectId):
        item_id = str(item_id)

    result[item_id] = {}

    for key, value in json_data.items():
        if key != "_id":
            if isinstance(value, list):
                array_id = f"{key}_id"
                arrays[array_id] = value
                result[item_id][array_id] = item_id
            else:
                result[item_id][key] = value

    if "tags_id" in result[item_id]:
        post_id = result[item_id].get("tags_id")
        result[item_id]["post_id"] = post_id

    return result, arrays

# Connecting to MongoDB
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.mongotest
collection = db.collectiontest

# Selecting n JSON documents from collection
n = 2
documents = collection.find().limit(n)
json_documents = [json.loads(json_util.dumps(document, default=json_util.default)) for document in documents]

# Appending all JSONs into one
output = {}
extracted_arrays = {}

for doc in json_documents:
    processed_doc, arrays = process_json(doc)
    item_id = list(processed_doc.keys())[0]
    output[item_id] = processed_doc[item_id]

    for array_id, array_values in arrays.items():
        if array_id in extracted_arrays:
            extracted_arrays[array_id].extend(array_values)
        else:
            extracted_arrays[array_id] = array_values

# Creating main output CSV file
with open("output.csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames_output = list(output[list(output.keys())[0]].keys())
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames_output)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(output.values())

# Creating tags CSV file
with open("tags.csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['tags'])
    writer.writerows([[tag] for tag in extracted_arrays['tags_id']])

# Creating comments CSV file
with open("comments.csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames_com = extracted_arrays['comments_id'][0].keys()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames_com)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(extracted_arrays['comments_id'])

# Printing output and extracted arrays for easier visual control
print("Extracted arrays:")
for array_id, array_values in extracted_arrays.items():
    print(array_id, ":", array_values)

print("\nOutput:")
print(json.dumps(output, indent=2))
```

An example of the JSONs that the code takes from the MongoDB:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9"
  },
  "body": "Amendment",
  "permalink": "aRjNnLZkJkTyspAIoRGe",
  "author": "machine",
  "title": "Bill of Rights",
  "tags": [
    "watchmaker",
    "santa",
    "xylophone",
    "math",
    "handsaw",
    "dream",
    "undershirt",
    "dolphin",
    "tanker",
    "action"
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "body": "Lorem ",
      "email": "HvizfYVx@pKvLaagH.com",
      "author": "Santiago Dollins"
    },
    {
      "body": "Lorem",
      "email": "WpOUCpdD@hccdxJvT.com",
      "author": "Jaclyn Morado"
    },
    {
      "body": "Loremid est laborum",
      "email": "OgDzHfFN@cWsDtCtx.com",
      "author": "Houston Valenti"
    }
  ],
  "date": {
    "$date": "2012-11-20T05:05:15.231Z"
  }
}]
```

I'm not sure whether to add the post_id's to all the comments and tags at the stage of creating the process_json function or at the stage of writing to CSVs and how to do it in general. Any advice would be appreciated a lot!!

Comment: Hi! Please edit your question to include samples of the CSVs you'd like, given the JSON sample you shared. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't included a sample of the expected output CSVs given the sample JSON, I really don't know what you want.

**I've interpreted** your question and code to mean you want something like the following:

```
docs.csv
========
| id                       | body      | permalink            | author  | title          | date                     |
|--------------------------|-----------|----------------------|---------|----------------|--------------------------|
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | Amendment | aRjNnLZkJkTyspAIoRGe | machine | Bill of Rights | 2012-11-20T05:05:15.231Z |

comments.csv
============
| id                       | body                | email                 | author           |
|--------------------------|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------|
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | Lorem               | HvizfYVx@pKvLaagH.com | Santiago Dollins |
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | Lorem               | WpOUCpdD@hccdxJvT.com | Jaclyn Morado    |
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | Loremid est laborum | OgDzHfFN@cWsDtCtx.com | Houston Valenti  |

tags.csv
========
| id                       | tag        |
|--------------------------|------------|
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | watchmaker |
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | santa      |
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | xylophone  |
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | math       |
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | handsaw    |
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | dream      |
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | undershirt |
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | dolphin    |
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | tanker     |
| 50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9 | action     |
```

If that **looks close** to what you want, read on.

I believe you simply need to iterate the comments and tags lists and for each thing you find in there, associate the doc's ID and save it to a new "row" in its own structure, so I made these structures to hold the final rows:

```py
doc_rows = []
comment_rows = []
tag_rows = []
```

I simplified your `process_json()` function to target the keys and objects/dicts that I can see in the sample JSON:

```py
def process(doc: dict[str, Any]):
    """Get the ID for doc, then associate that ID with doc's comments and tags saving each in their own lists."""
    id_ = doc["_id"]["$oid"]

    for comment_dict in doc["comments"]:
        comment_rows.append({"id": id_, **comment_dict})

    for tag in doc["tags"]:
        tag_rows.append({"id": id_, "tag": tag})

    del doc["_id"]
    del doc["comments"]
    del doc["tags"]

    doc["date"] = doc["date"]["$date"]

    doc_rows.append({"id": id_, **doc})
```

Some things to note about that code:

- I use the form `{"id": id_, ...}` to build a new dict so that the id key comes first.  `{"id": id_, **comment_dict}` means create a new dict with key "id" then follow on with all the key-value pairs from comment_dict.
- With the comments and tags lists saved to their own rows, I delete them from the doc before adding the doc to its own list of rows.
- I also thought it might be nice to have date as just a string value instead of a JSON object/Python dict, so I replaced the dict with the final value.

Running that on your sample JSON creates the final _rows lists:

```py
docs = json.load(open("input.json"))
for doc in docs:
    process(doc)


print(doc_rows)
# [
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "body": "Amendment", "permalink": "aRjNnLZkJkTyspAIoRGe", "author": "machine", "title": "Bill of Rights", "date": "2012-11-20T05:05:15.231Z"}
# ]
print(comment_rows)
# [
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "body": "Lorem ", "email": "HvizfYVx@pKvLaagH.com", "author": "Santiago Dollins"},
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "body": "Lorem", "email": "WpOUCpdD@hccdxJvT.com", "author": "Jaclyn Morado"},
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "body": "Loremid est laborum", "email": "OgDzHfFN@cWsDtCtx.com", "author": "Houston Valenti"},
# ]
print(tag_rows)
# [
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "tag": "watchmaker"},
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "tag": "santa"},
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "tag": "xylophone"},
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "tag": "math"},
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "tag": "handsaw"},
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "tag": "dream"},
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "tag": "undershirt"},
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "tag": "dolphin"},
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "tag": "tanker"},
#     {"id": "50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9", "tag": "action"},
# ]
```

From there, creating the CSVs just requires creating the DictWriters (like you did), though you can just give each DictWriter the first row from each list to setup the fieldnames:

```py
with open("output/docs.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=doc_rows[0])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(doc_rows)

with open("output/comments.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=comment_rows[0])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(comment_rows)

with open("output/tags.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=tag_rows[0])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(tag_rows)
```